# Delete data from Azure table

Tags: c#, azure, windows-mobile

I have database in Azure. In column DeleteDate is date, when this row should be delete.  How I can check and delete rows, which DeleteDate is today?

Answer (score 1):

Using TSQL you can: 
DELETE Table WHERE CONVERT(DATE,DeleteDate) = CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE())